# Grouping column data with common value or else show default text

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, grouping

I want to achieve the following transformation:

**Sample Data**

```
SELECT NumWURm,ReportAText,ReportBText,ReportCText,ReportDText,ReportEText,ReportFText 
FROM t_SchFacility 
WHERE  FacID IN (483,485)
```

Result:

```
NumWURm ReportAText       ReportBText   ReportCText ReportDText ReportEText ReportFText

3       Report On venue   Warm Up       Photo       Get Set     
2       Report On venue   Warm Up       Photo
```

**Desired Output**

I want to to get the common column values to be shown as it is, in case the values differ, I want to show some default text.

```
NumWURm ReportAText      ReportBText    ReportCText ReportDText   ReportEText   ReportFText

3       Report On venue  Warm Up        Photo       Default Text
```

Comment: When you say "common column values", to which columns are you referring?  More specifically `NumWURm` differs in value yet `3` is returned.  Whereas the difference in `ReportEText` has the `default text` indicated by your problem statement.  So what determines which `NumWURm` is returned and are differences to be reported on all OTHER columns?

Comment: differences are to be reported for other columns. in case of numWURm we need the max value

Comment: Also, when you say "values differ" do you mean any of the values in the result set described by the `where` predicate?  In other words had your example contained 5 rows instead of 2 with 3 rows having an empty `ReportDText` and two rows having `Get Set`, would the output have still been the single row?  Is there ever a case where the output will be anything other than a single row?

Answer (score 1):

This is just the case for my favourite MIN = MAX trick.  When MIN and MAX are the same, then there's only one value, and either the MIN or the MAX can be used as THE value.

```
SELECT     
    MAX(NumWURm) as NumWURm,
    CASE WHEN MIN(ReportAText) = MAX(ReportAText) 
        THEN MIN(ReportAText)
        ELSE 'Default'
    END,
    CASE WHEN MIN(ReportBText) = MAX(ReportBText) 
        THEN MIN(ReportBText)
        ELSE 'Default'
    END,
    CASE WHEN MIN(ReportCText) = MAX(ReportCText) 
        THEN MIN(ReportCText)
        ELSE 'Default'
    END,
    CASE WHEN MIN(ReportDText) = MAX(ReportDText) 
        THEN MIN(ReportDText)
        ELSE 'Default'
    END,
    CASE WHEN MIN(ReportEText) = MAX(ReportEText) 
        THEN MIN(ReportEText)
        ELSE 'Default'
    END,
    CASE WHEN MIN(ReportFText) = MAX(ReportFText) 
        THEN MIN(ReportFText)
        ELSE 'Default'
    END
FROM t_SchFacility 
WHERE  FacID IN (483,485)
```

If you need this to be *really* specific, you may need to specify a collation option for the string comparison (e.g. if case difference is significant to you).

Answer (score 0):

The following would produce a single row of output for a non-empty set.

```
with [Selected] ([NumWURm], [ReportAText], [ReportBText], [ReportCText], [ReportDText], [ReportEText], [ReportFText])
(
    select [NumWURm], [ReportAText], [ReportBText], [ReportCText], [ReportDText], [ReportEText], [ReportFText]
    from [t_SchFacility]
    where [FacID] IN (483, 485)
),
  [Number_Selected] ([count])
(
    selected count(*)
    from [Selected]
),
  [ReportAText] ([ReportAText])
(
    select s.[ReportAText], n.[count]
    from [Selected] as s cross join [Number_Selected] as n
    group by s.[ReportAText], n.[count]
    having count(*) = n.[count]
),
...
  [ReportFText] ([ReportFText])
(
    select s.[ReportFText], n.[count]
    from [Selected] as s cross join [Number_Selected] as n
    group by s.[ReportFText], n.[count]
    having count(*) = n.[count]
)
select
    max(s.[NumWURm]) as 'NumWuRm',
    a.coalesce([ReportAText], 'Default Text') as 'ReportAText',
    b.[ReportBText] as 'ReportBText',
    c.[ReportCText] as 'ReportCText',
    d.[ReportDText] as 'ReportDText',
    e.[ReportEText] as 'ReportEText',
    f.[ReportFText] as 'ReportFText'
from
    [Selected] as s
        left outer join
    [ReportAText] as a
        on (null is null)
        left outer join
    ...
    [ReportFText] as f
        on (null is null)
```

This is a code outline and so will require suitable testing and adjustment.